# Windows XP Will Not Restart

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, shutdown, reboot

I have a Dell Precision T5500 that is dual-booted with Windows XP and Windows 7.

Previously, when shutting down Windows XP (fresh installation) it would sit at the "*Windows is shutting down...*" screen and I would have to force power it off when the hard drive light showed that the computer was idle.

After installing the motherboard's chipset drivers this problem was solved, however the restart function still doesn't work.

It will shutdown the OS and the monitor will shut off, but the computer will remain on until I force power it off and restart it manually.

Is there any ideas as to what could be causing this or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a power management issue.

Please check Control Panel → Power Options and if there is an APM tab → check the "*Enable Advanced Power Management support* " option and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks - however since this is a server computer with multiple processors the APM tab is not available.